# How to select a class object by using one of its attributes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding with C# in Unity using Visual studio. I am trying to select an object that is made from a class by using a "position" value. I'm struggling to explain it, but essentially I have a canvas called Counties and inside are a couple of UI objects, such as Leinster and Connacht:

[image: Screenshot]

I run through all the children of that canvas Counties to select them all one by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Counties.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    Transform t = Counties.transform.GetChild(i);
    Current = t.name;
}
```

However, I also need to change some values of each those children as they each have an object in my script which corresponds to each one. For example in the code below that is the object that corresponds to Leinster.

```
public County Leinster = new County(2630000, "NorthernIreland", "Connacht", "Munster", "Wales", 0);
```

The thing I don't know how to do is to actually connect those two. I have put in a "position" value in the object, which is the last number. For Leinster it is 0 because that is the first child in the canvas Counties and the next one (Connacht) would be 1 and so on. My question is basically how would I use that number to select the corresponding class object that has the same number as its "position"? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: he warning you saw was the website noticing that you had likely pasted code, but not marked it as code.   It looks like @Alex has already cleaned this up for you.    For future, the editor has an icon with two curly braces  {}   that you use to mark code sections as code.    Highlight the part that is code and click that icon.

Comment: To expand on that, formatting small bits of code is as simple as placing 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Is `Counties.transform` a list of counties?  If so, you can select specific objects by using LINQ: `var leinster = Counties.transform.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Position == 0)`  Then you can modify it provided your properties have a `set`ter:  `leinster.Name = "foo"`

Comment: Hey thanks for telling me, I tried using that button but it kept saying the code was incorrectly formatted, maybe because I used tab to make indents instead of spaces.

Comment: I dont get it if you already have `Counties` why do you also have `Leinster`as a public variable?

Comment: @Kyle Counties.transform is a background object in Unity (the one shown in the picture) and inside are a bunch of textlabels and images which are all the different counties. Thanks for the answer though, what is a set ter?

Comment: @AliKanat Well there are 14 counties in total, I assumed it would be easier to make a class object for each one rather than assigning the actual objects a bunch of attributes

Comment: @Simply Can you put it into a collection instead?  `public List<County> Counties {get; set;}` <-- a setter method allows you to set a `value` to an object.

Comment: Can you share the line of code where you define `Counties` ? Is this an array of game objects or what? I am really confused what you are trying to do. What are you gonna use those attributes for? Change something in the canvas?

Comment: @AliKanat Well it's just a public gameobject. The line is public GameObject Counties; and the gameobject links Counties to the Counties object that is shown in the picture at the top. So the for loop runs through all 14 counties inside it.

Comment: @Kyle I will take a look at using a collection, it seems quite a bit more complicated though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right you want to access your script component assigned to children of your parent. You can use the `GetComponent` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Counties.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    Transform t = Counties.transform.GetChild(i);
    Current = t.name;
    County county = t.GetComponent<County>();

    //do something with county object...
}
```

You can also add the component to your object first if there is none:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Counties.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    Transform t = Counties.transform.GetChild(i);
    Current = t.name;
    County county = t.GetComponent<County>();
    if (county == null)
       county = t.gameObject.AddComponent<County>();

    //do something with county object...
    county.name = t.name;
}
```

If you are looking for an easy way to access your Counties you can also use Dictionary:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<string, County> Counties = new Dictionary<string, County>();

//add County to dictionary
Counties.Add("NorthernIreland", new County(2630000, "NorthernIreland", "Connacht", "Munster", "Wales", 0));

//get County from dictionary
Counties["NorthernIreland"] //and do something with it...
```